# EntityDataSource/DataQuery - how to use Include() correctly?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to use the Include property for an EntityDataSource that I've setup but I'm not sure how to follow the relationship. So I've got a DetailsView which looks like so:

[image]

As you can see there's a foreign key field in there. Ultimately what I'm trying to do is pull in the record that is attatched to that so I can show a different field (name) and a dropdown when editing.

My markup is fairly basic:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource runat="server" ID="efDataSource" OnContextCreating="On_ContextCreating" EntitySetName="FuelSurcharges" EnableUpdate="true" EnableInsert="true" EnableDelete="true" EnableFlattening="true" AutoPage="true" AutoSort="true" />
   <asp:DetailsView ID="dvSelectedRecord" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="true" DataSourceID="efDataSource" AutoGenerateInsertButton="true" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true">  
   </asp:DetailsView>
```

So I've come across the Include property on the EntityDataSource which I'm assuming is what I want to use. However I'm looking at my data backwards on this page for binding purposes:

```
  /// <summary>
/// Represents a Freight Company
/// </summary>
[Table("NetC_EF_FreightCompany")]
public class FreightCompany
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The ID of the Freight Company
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public Double CubicToKiloRatio { get; set; }
    public Boolean DeadweightCalculationEnabled { get; set; }
    public Boolean VolumetricWeightCalculationEnabled { get; set; }
    public Boolean LoadingMetreCalculationEnabled { get; set; }
    public Double CargoMeterHeightLookup { get; set; }
    public Double CargoMeterLookup { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Fuel Surcharges for this Company
    /// </summary>
    public ICollection<FuelSurcharge> FuelSurcharges { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a Fuel Surcharge
/// </summary>
[Table("NetC_EF_FuelSurcharge")]
public class FuelSurcharge
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The ID of the Fuel Surcharge
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ToDate { get; set; }
    public Double PercentageSurcharge { get; set; }
}
```

How do I go about including the FreightCompany (so I can use the Name property) when I don't have a Field that I can use - but I do have a Foreign Key ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you can use 'Back References' and that they solve the problem. I changed my FuelSurcharge to include an additional property:

```
public FreightCompany FreightCompany { get; set; }
```

Now I can add an include on the EntityDataSource:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource runat="server" ID="efDataSource" OnContextCreating="On_ContextCreating" EntitySetName="FuelSurcharges" EnableUpdate="true" EnableInsert="true" EnableDelete="true" EnableFlattening="true" AutoPage="true" AutoSort="true" Include="FreightCompany"/>
```

And can bind to additional values like so:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="FreightCompany.Name" HeaderText="Freight Company" />
```